# Azure Membership Provider using Table Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-membership

I've written a web application for the Azure cloud that uses the table storage asp.net membership provider for security.

I can get this running locally in the Developer Fabric with the application pointing to use the storage account in the cloud e.g. in web.config

```
 <membership defaultProvider="TableStorageMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="TableStorageMembershipProvider"
             type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageMembershipProvider"
             description="Membership provider using table storage"
             applicationName="AspProvidersDemo"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

and in ServiceConfiguration here:

```
<Setting name="DataConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyAccount;AccountKey=MyAccountKeyHere" />
```

It works locally, but when I deploy to the cloud, I cannot log in due to invalid password even though I'm using the same account and code that works in the DevFabric. The only thing I can think of is that it's something to do with the Salt as the account I'm trying to log in with is created locally.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I appreciate I can go through and put trace statements everywhere - just trying to save myself some time!

Update: Seems to work when using Clear Text password. Must be a difference between how my local machine and Azure is computing the hash.

Answer (score 0):

I would be that your machine key on local being diff to Azure.  The users you created on dev fabric pointing to Azure storage would be with different machine keys than to what is used in Windows Azure.

Although the specific issue described here is fixed in 1.4 i still think if you are using local pointing to the same storage account as your windows azure service does then you may still have to do the following - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg494983.aspx